# RxJava 2 + Room Transactions: Return single Disposable in transaction of two rxjava opertions

Tags: database, transactions, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I am using Room database and RxJava.
I need to delete all records from a table and then insert new set of entries.

A way to do this would be:

```
@Transaction
fun clearAndInsert(records: List<Whatever>): Disposable {
    deleteRecords()
    insertRecords(records)
}
```

`deleteRecords()` returns a disposable
 and `insertRecords()` returns a disposable.
However, I would like to return a single Disposable from this method. Although I could return a CompositeDisposable.
So what I though of is:

```
@Transaction
override fun clearAndInsertTags(records: List<Whatever>): Disposable {
    return Observable.fromCallable { subscriptionsDao.deleteRecords() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                insertRecords(records)
            })
}
```

This will return single disposable. However, would this be transaction? Lets say, for whatever reason, `insertRecords()` failed and onError is called. Would Room actually revert deletion of all records for me? If not, what would be the correct way of achieving this? Or is returning a `CompositeDisposable` is the right way?

Comment: when you do this...
```.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                insertRecords(records)
            })```
`insertRecords` method runs on main thread and Room doesn't allow db operations on main thread.

Comment: `insertRecords` has its own `subscribeOn/observeOn` so it is not on main thread.

Comment: You can try with [Zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html). It combines two streams into one.

Comment: But that would not work as a transaction I suppose?

Comment: Faced such issue with error `Method annotated with @Transaction must not return deferred/async return type io.reactivex.Single`. Possibly Google does not ever keep in mind Rx while increasing shine and quality of their brand new LiveData. Suppose the best solution is to forget raw and buggy Room in preference of Requery.